# Why is the result value of a generator function using the yield keyword different?

Tags: python

I am curious as to why the result values of the two conditions are different with the generator function using the yield below.

```
def test():
    print("function has been called.")
    yield 1
    print("The function was called a second time.")
    yield 2

print("A passing")

t = test()

a = next(t)
print(a)

b = next(t)
print(b)
```

```
def test():
    print("function has been called.")
    yield 1
    print("The function was called a second time.")
    yield 2

print("A Passing")

t = test()

a = next(t)
b = next(t)

print(a)
print(b)
```

Comment: The only difference is the order of the output lines, right?  And that's because your statement order is different.  The second `print` in the function gets printed when you call `next()` the second time.   `a` and `b` contain integers; they do not contain iterators or generators.

Comment: I'm going to GUESS that you expected the result of the `next()` call to be some kind of `future` that wasn't resolved until the value was used.  That's not how generators work.  You CAN get that kind of effect with `await`/`async`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an annotated version of your source that shows what prints when:

```
def test():
    print("function has been called.")
    yield 1
    print("The function was called a second time.")
    yield 2

print("A passing")

t = test()

a = next(t)     # prints "Function has been called"
print(a)        # prints 1

b = next(t)     # prints "The function was called a second time"
print(b)        # prints 2

print("A Passing")

t = test()

a = next(t)     # prints "Function has been called"
b = next(t)     # prints "The function was called a second time"

print(a)        # prints 1
print(b)        # prints 2
```